# Eureka - Can't get a response - Can't contact any eureka nodes

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a Eureka server running on port 8761 (localhost:8761/eureka) and I have a Zuul application that I would like to register with eureka, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Can't get a response from http://localhost:8761/eurekaapps/ZUULSERVER
Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?

java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:606)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1596)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my application.yml for the zuul application:

```
info:
  component: Zuul Server

eureka:
  server:
    enabled: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false  

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  route:
    discovery:
      url: http://localhost:9000/polaris/discovery 
      path: /polaris/discovery/**
    sla:
      url: http://localhost:9000/polaris/sla
      path: /polaris/sla/**
    stores: /stores/**
    customers: /customers/**

#remove when spring-boot 1.2.1 is out
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
management:
  security:
    enabled:
      false

server:
  port: 8765

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Did I just mess up one of these values and so zuul is unable to see the eureka server? It seems like it is not registering properly. Maybe I missed a crucial parameter in the application.yml file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The clue is "eurekaapps" in the error. You need a trailing "/" in the service URL:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

(which is the default anyway I think).

Comment: I am getting Read Timed out exception. Though at first its getting registered with Eureka server but then its unable to send heartbeat to server saying timed out.

Comment: Remote eureka client throwing read time out exception stating that Can't  get a response from `http://192.168.1.12:8761/eureka/apps/USERSERVICE/dev39.local:userservice:8181`. but when I hit this url in browser, I get response of that host. What could be the possible issue ?

Comment: @agpt did you find any resolutions for this?